# How do you change Visual Studio's default web browser?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, browser

This is a for a Silverlight project that isn't anchored to an .aspx file, so right clicking, etc. is a bit out of the question. Any ideas?

Edit:

Add an .html file, then click it. Really dumb. Last time I ask a question at three in the morning.

Comment: If you close as a duplicate, you need to provide a link to the dupe in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is right-clicking out of the question? With any HTML document at least (even in *Miscellaneous Files*) you can right-click on it, select *Browse With...*, select the browser, and click on ***Set as Default***. If the browser doesn't appear in the list, click on *Add...*.

Answer (score 0):

Default Browser Changer extension:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/233945ae-0b7b-47e7-9b02-c5a11798afb5