# VS 2008 Opens Default Browser instead of IE for SilverLight Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, silverlight, internet-explorer

My default browser is Chrome.
When I run my web applications within VS 2008 IDE, it uses chrome.

I want to use IE for this. Is there an option in VS 2008 to make IE the browser to load the web applications?

I just want this when using VS 2008 - I don't want to change my default browser each time otherwise.

EDIT: when creating a silverlight application.

Comment: Exact Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-default-browser-instead-of-ie

Comment: This is for silverlight application. There is no browse with when i right click on any time in the solution explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question: [How do you change Visual Studio's default web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181992/how-do-you-change-visual-studios-default-web-browser)

But basically, **create an html file inside your silverlight project**, right click on it, select browse with... set the default browser. Now you can erase the html if you want to. The next time you debug your project, it will open with the browser you specified for the html file.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on .aspx file in your solution tree, and click Browse With...
then specify your default browser.

---

Comment: okay i am using silverlight... Silverlight page... how can i do it in that?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into project properties.
The principle should be the same.

Comment: I can't find it. Do you know where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a post-build event that runs FireFox.exe, pointing to the url of your website.  You can edit post-build events by right-clicking on your Web Application, going to Compile, and clicking the Build Events button.  Your post-build command could be something like "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://localhost/mysite for example.

Comment: I don't see compile item when I right click. I am using SIlverlight btw.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only have a Silverlight project in your solution. You need to add a web site like ASP.NET to your solution to use Browse With and post-build commands.

Comment: I agree the solution is to add a Web Site/App project to the solution but what would the post-build commands do?